# ReactJS using Link/Route on click of search

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a holding page for search results:

```
import React from "react";

class SearchResults extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1 style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>
        Search result
        </h1>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default SearchResults;
```

Now I a function defined

```
searchById = (Id) => {
    console.log("On Id Search=", Id);
    this.setState({Id: this.Id});
    // <Link
    //   to={{
    //     pathname: "/resultForSearchWitId",
    //     search: "?Id="+Id,
    //     hash: "#searchResults",
    //     state: {fromDashboard: true}
    //   }}
    // return <Link to="#/searchResults" />;
    // return <Redirect to="/" />;
    console.log(this.props.history);
   this.props.history.pathname = 'searchResults';
  };
```

Ideally, I would like to use Link to route the content of the result to be loaded onto the searchResuts.js file. I have defined the Route as

```
      <Route path="/searchResults" component={SearchResults} />
```

When the app launches I have the following Route

```
      <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
```

Which works and all the menu items also work well with the above code, but my search results JS file is never invoked.

What am I missing? I am using ant.design and ReactJS for my menu and input design.

Even `this.props.history.pathname = 'searchResults';` does not work. The current designed holding page does not load.

Update: Router stub code

```
<Router>
    <Layout style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <Sider
        collapsible
        collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
        onCollapse={this.onCollapse}
      >
        <Search
          placeholder="Search by ID"
          onSearch={this.searchById}
          style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
        />

        <Menu theme="dark" defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]} mode="inline">
          <SubMenu
            key="0"
            title={
              <span>
                <Icon type="appstore" />
                <span>Test App</span>
              </span>
            }
          >
            <Menu.Item key="0-1">
              <span>Dummy Link 1</span>
              <Link to="/dummyLink1" />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="0-2">
              <span>Dummy Link 2</span>
              <Link to="/dummpyLink2" />
            </Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
        </Menu>
      </Sider>
      <Layout>
        <Header style={{ background: "#fff", padding: 0, paddingLeft: 16 }}>
          <Icon
            className="trigger"
            type={this.state.collapsed ? "menu-unfold" : "menu-fold"}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            onClick={this.toggle}
          />
        </Header>
        <Content
          style={{
            margin: "24px 16px",
            padding: 24,
            background: "#fff",
            minHeight: 280,
          }}
        >
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/searchResults" component={SearchResults} />
          <Route path="/dummpyLink1" component={DummyLink1} />
          <Route path="/dummpyLink2" component={DummyLink2} />
        </Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  </Router>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do `this.props.history.push("/searchResults");`? This with some route state to be received by the `SearchResults ` component?

Comment: You are mixing the location and history objects, try using the `history.push` or `history.replace`methods.

Comment: If after using the `push()` method of history, the route still does not change correctly, and the main dashboard page renders still, I think the problem might be inside the component which you've defined all routes and it causes the routes not to switch properly.

Comment: Its possible, I inherited the code 4 days ago and today I came across this problem, been trying all combinations, nothing working so far. Hence the request for help here!

Answer (score 0):

If `searchById` function redirects to the seaech results page, you need to add the following line inside it:

`this.props.history.push('/searchResults)`

Comment: When I do this @Saba, the problem is that is my URL is link http://localhost:8080/dashboard, the push will make it http://localhost:8080/dasboard#/searchResults, so it does not load the page.

Comment: How did you define the routes of the project? It would be good if we could see that how did you write the components which contains all the routings

Comment: import SearchResults from "../../../containers/Dashboard/SearchResults";              <Route path="/searchResults" component={SearchResults} />
Typically invoking like <Link to="/searchRsults"/>

Comment: No, 

I am asking the way you define the routes. For example:

`<BroweserRouter><Switch>....</Switch></BroweserRouter>`

Comment: @Vivek Please check and ensure you are doing `push("/searchResults")` and ***not*** `push("#/searchResults")`.

Answer (score 0):

use **`push()`** method and you can pass parameters as well

```
searchById = (Id) => {
    console.log("On Id Search=", Id);
    this.setState({Id: this.Id});
   this.props.history.push({
     pathname: "/searchResults",
     search: "?Id="+Id,
     state: {fromDashboard: true}
   });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem I am trying to solve here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to imperatively navigate to your `SearchResults` page component then you should do a history push to the path and pass along any data in route state.

```
searchById = (Id) => {
  console.log("On Id Search=", Id);
  this.setState({Id: this.Id});
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/searchResults',
    state: {
      searchResults: /* the search result data */,
    },
  });
};
```

On the receiving route component access route state from the `location` prop.

```
class SearchResults extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { location: { state: { searchResults } } } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1 style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>
        Search result
        </h1>
        {searchResults.map(...)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```